# Getting SIGNATURE (parameter names) MISMATCH with Java POST but not with curl.

Tags: java, oracle, curl, plsql, screen-scraping

curl works fine with a list of parameters (curl -d), but when I run a post using OpenURL, I'm getting a SIGNATURE MISMATCH. 
I find it difficult to understand what is missing.

This works:

```
     $ curl -d
     "term_in=201510&sel_subj=dummy&sel_day=dummy&sel_schd=dummy&sel_insm=dummy&sel_camp=dummy&sel_levl=dummy&sel_sess=dummy&sel_instr=dummy&sel_ptrm=dummy&sel_attr=dummy&sel_subj=%&sel_crse=&sel_title=&sel_from_cred=&sel_to_cred=&sel_camp=%25&sel_levl=%25&begin_hh=0&begin_mi=0&begin_ap=a&end_hh=0&end_mi=0&end_ap=a"
     https://somesite.ca/banprod/bwckschd.p_get_crse_unsec
```

This fails:

```
    NameValuePair[] data = {
        new NameValuePair("term_code", termCode),           
        new NameValuePair("sel_subj", "dummy"),
        new NameValuePair("sel_day", "dummy"),
        new NameValuePair("sel_day", "dummy"),
        new NameValuePair("sel_insm", "dummy"),
        new NameValuePair("sel_insm", "dummy"),
        new NameValuePair("sel_camp", "dummy"),
        new NameValuePair("sel_levl", "dummy"),
        new NameValuePair("sel_sess", "dummy"),
        new NameValuePair("sel_instr", "dummy"),
        new NameValuePair("sel_ptrm", "dummy"),
        new NameValuePair("sel_attr", "dummy"),
        new NameValuePair("sel_subj", "%"),
        new NameValuePair("sel_crse", ""),
        new NameValuePair("sel_title", ""),
        new NameValuePair("sel_from_cred", ""),
        new NameValuePair("sel_to_cred", ""),
        new NameValuePair("sel_camp", "%25"),
        new NameValuePair("sel_levl", "%25"),
        new NameValuePair("begin_hh", "0"),
        new NameValuePair("begin_mi", "0"),
        new NameValuePair("begin_ap", "a"),
        new NameValuePair("end_hh", "0"),
        new NameValuePair("end_mi", "0"),
        new NameValuePair("end_ap", "a")
    };

    doc = openURL.post(url, data);
```

Returned from somesite.ca

```
    Failed to parse target procedure 
    bwysched.p_course_search: SIGNATURE (parameter names) MISMATCH
    VARIABLES IN FORM NOT IN PROCEDURE: SEL_INSTR,SEL_PTRM,SEL_CRSE,SEL_TITLE,SEL_FROM_CRED,SEL_TO_CRED,BEGIN_HH,BEGIN_MI,BEGIN_AP,END_HH,END_MI,END_AP
    NON-DEFAULT VARIABLES IN PROCEDURE NOT IN FORM: WSEA_CODE,SESSION_ID,SEL_SCHD,SEL_LINK,SEL_INSTRUCT,SEL_OPEN,SEL_RESD,SEL_WAIT,SEL_BEGIN_HH,SEL_BEGIN_MI,SEL_BEGIN_AM_PM,SEL_END_HH,SEL_END_MI,SEL_END_AM_PM

      DAD name: banprod
      PROCEDURE  : bwysched.p_course_search
      URL        : http://banssbprod.tru.ca:443/banprod/bwysched.p_course_search
      PARAMETERS :
      ===========
      TERM_CODE:
       201510
      SEL_SUBJ:
       dummy
       %
      SEL_DAY:
       dummy
       dummy
      SEL_INSM:
       dummy
       dummy
      SEL_CAMP:
       dummy
       %25
      SEL_LEVL:
       dummy
       %25
      SEL_SESS:
       dummy
      SEL_INSTR:
       dummy
      SEL_PTRM:
       dummy
      SEL_ATTR:
       dummy
      SEL_CRSE:

      SEL_TITLE:

      SEL_FROM_CRED:

      SEL_TO_CRED:

      BEGIN_HH:
       0
      BEGIN_MI:
       0
      BEGIN_AP:
       a
      END_HH:
       0
      END_MI:
       0
      END_AP:
       a
```

Comment: For the first parameter in the curl code you have term_in and in the procedure you have term_code.  Not sure if this is the issue but could explain the error.

Comment: Thanks, foggy brain today! There were a couple problems with my implementation, and yes, using term_code was one of them.